# Number of possible balanced binary trees

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees, binary-trees, counting

A tree is *balanced* if the subtrees of each node differ in height by at most one.

> How many balanced binary trees can we create from $n$ nodes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: @ShivDuttSharma A tree that it's left and right sub-trees are balanced and the difference between height of left and right sub-trees is less than one. (Recursively for all sub-trees)